# Better word for inferring variables other than var

Tags: c#, language-design

This might get closed, but I'll try anyway.

I was showing a VB6 programmer some of my C# code the other day and he noticed the var keyword and was like "Oh a variant type, that's not really strong typing when you do that."  and I had to go on the typical "var != VARIANT" speech to explain to him that it is not a variant it just compiler inferred.

I was thinking about other words they (C# team) could have used so this kind of thing didn't happen.  I personally like *infer*, something like:

```
 infer person = new Person("Bob");
```

I know this is not really that big of deal, but just curious to see what other people would use to do the same thing.

I have made this a community wiki because it doesn't really have an answer.

Comment: infer a nickel, infer a dime.

Comment: youfigureitout person = new Person("Bob");

Comment: There something about var that strikes a good chord with me.

Comment: Infer is excellent.  Says exactly what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++0x uses the "auto" keyword for type inference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference

That's not a bad trade-off for those guys since "auto" was (AFAIK) already a keyword. I can imagine it in C#:

```
auto i = 3;
```

I do like "infer" though (but then I don't have any problem with "var" either).

Comment: `auto` was indeed a keyword so it was a prime candidate for reuse, but it also sounds right. It was also picked up by D language in the same context, so it's kinda growing.

Comment: Particularly since it was a completely useless keyword.

Comment: Terrible keyword.  You might as well have another one called "matic".  Then you would have a matching pair like foo and bar.

Comment: I preffer auto, then if they decide to partially infer a type it will sound better than var: 
Expression<Func<Customer, auto>> selector = c=>new {c.Name, c.Age };

Answer (score 4):

```
thisappearsweaklytypedbutisactuallystronglytyped i = 3;
```

It's the only way to avoid confusion! Don't worry, autocomplete means it won't really take that much longer to type...

Answer (score 3):

How about reviving ye olde `BASIC` keyword `LET`?

```
let answer = 42;
```

Comment: The VB6 guys will still get confused then; the Let keyword (on a property) is used only for simple data typles, while Set is used only for objects.

Answer (score 2):

But "***infer***" is 2 more characters than "***var***"...  Maybe "var" wasn't the best thing to put in front of a VB6 programmer at first...

Comment: I was trying to think of something better then "infer" but "inf" didn't feel right and was to close to int, and "fer"... just plain wrong.

Comment: Haha it should just be "v":   v dog = new Dog(); would be much better!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great idea. I myself have had to explain the var keyword from time to time and how it is really just a placeholder for a type and that it still insures strong typing.

***infer*** works for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about **foo** ?

Comment: yeah, so much better than var ;)

Comment: I think we also need a "bar" keyword.  Maybe for throwing exceptions you can have "foobar NotImplementedException()"

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, Pascal/Delphi and ActionScript programmers immediately grasp the true meaning of `var`. So why single out VB6? It is unfortunate that it had `Variant` in it, and so VB6 guys quickly substitute `var` for that, but no matter which way you go, someone somewhere will be confused.

Given that VB6 is legacy for quite a while now anyway, that `var` is perfectly clear to someone without the burden of past experience (I mean, how many people new to programming would think of `var` meaning something different from "variable"?), and that `var` has been specifically used to mean "variable" by several other popular languages, it doesn't seem like a bad choice.

The obvious problem I see with `infer` keyword as given is that it's not obvious that it infers the type of variable. Just looking at it, it might as well be inferring its value or something (especially if RHS is not a `new`-statement).

Answer (score 1):

I like `var`, and think the meaning in the context of a strongly-typed language is clear. `dynamic`, on the other hand, is the "oddball" in C# code so the longer semantic naming is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

C# is supposed to be all symbolly, like C++, not all keywordy, like VB. How about "**?**"

```
? X = 5;
? Y = X.ToString();
? Z = Y + Y;
```

What type is Z? Who knows?

Comment: A string? Anyway, '?' is taken for the conditional operator.

Comment: I just love that "symbolly" C++ feel every time I type `reinterpret_cast` or `static_assert`...

Comment: this could possibly get confused with a nullable type at times (cant think of any offhand), but i like it overall.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, a symbol can be used more than once. When would this re-use result in ambiguity? The colon is used for both the inheritance operator and the conditional operator.
@Pavel Minaev, I see what you mean. C++ does have some aweful keywords, and the underscores are the icing on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

I think C# would be better with no "static type inference" keyword at all. So it would work like this:

```
myDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
```

I was wondering why C# designers felt a keyword like "var" was needed for static type inference. Was it necessary to comply with C#'s fundamental grammar rules? Was it because they had already thought about "dynamic" and wanted to make the distinction more clear between static and dynamic type inference?

In any case, after some prolonged exposure to Python, "var" (or any alternative keyword or qualifier) feels completely superfluous. Take the following code:

```
foreach ( item in myList ) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

What additional information would adding "var" in front of "item" give to the reader?

Comment: "var" tells the reader that the programmer didn't just make a dumb mistake and leave off the type. I bet it's a lot easier for the parser, as well. Only a guess, but I bet starting with a keyword helps the parser get it's bearings.

Comment: @John Saunders: Or make an even dumber mistake and misspell the variable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It doesn't allow you to misspell the variable. If you misspell it at declaration, you'll have to continue to misspell it whenever you use it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: If one had a variable called `MyDict` and the statement above were a legal way of declaring `myDict`, then trying to say `MyDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>` but mistyping the name as `myDict` would cause the compiler to create a new variable while leaving `MyDict` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If the keyword was named `variable` instead of `var`, then we may not see this kind of confusion.  This may have been the intent, but someone clearly thought that typing `variable` was too verbose, leading to the ambiguity we have today.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely on topic, but VB.NET does this almost too cleanly. I bet it's even more confusing for ex VB6 users.

```
Dim p = New Person()
```

Is that using late binding or type inference? Better check your project properties.

Comment: I refer "Dim P = New Person()" for the case where the initial value is a constructor expression.